# Understanding the behaviour of case statement in switch

Tags: c

```
int a=4;
int b=4;

int main()
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            {
             case 4:
                  b=7;
             case 5:
                  b=8; //added newly to check in disassembly
            }
        break;
    }
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the value of "b" printed is 8. Why does the code execute the inner case statement,though the external case condition is not satisfied? Does the switch behave directly as a  goto label irrespective of where the case label has been placed?

```
Update: Disassembly code
    25:         switch(a) 
    26:         { 
    27:                         case 1: 
    28:                                         { 
0x00000200 481A      LDR      r0,[pc,#104]  ; @0x0000026C
0x00000202 6800      LDR      r0,[r0,#0x00]
0x00000204 2801      CMP      r0,#0x01
0x00000206 D004      BEQ      0x00000212
0x00000208 2804      CMP      r0,#0x04
0x0000020A D003      BEQ      0x00000214
0x0000020C 2805      CMP      r0,#0x05
0x0000020E D109      BNE      0x00000224
0x00000210 E004      B        0x0000021C
    29:                                          case 4: 
0x00000212 BF00      NOP      
    30:                                                                 b=7; 
0x00000214 2007      MOVS     r0,#0x07
0x00000216 4916      LDR      r1,[pc,#88]  ; @0x00000270
0x00000218 6008      STR      r0,[r1,#0x00]
    31:                                          case 5: 
0x0000021A BF00      NOP      
    32:                                                                 b=8; 
    33:  
    34:                                         } 
0x0000021C 2008      MOVS     r0,#0x08
0x0000021E 4914      LDR      r1,[pc,#80]  ; @0x00000270
0x00000220 6008      STR      r0,[r1,#0x00]
    35:                         break; 
    36:         } 
    37:
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about C programming in general and not specific to embedded systems.

Comment: As for your question, I have no idea what the extra braces do, but in C, generally if you don't include a `break` at the end of a switch case, execution falls through to the next line of code, even if it's in another case.

Comment: Should probably be migrated to StackOverflow. It's not a terrible question, just not the right SE for it.

Comment: "Does the switch behave directly as a goto label irrespective of where the case label has been placed?" Yes, the case statement even has the same syntax as a label to be used for goto.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, It's almost certainly a duplicate on SO.

Comment: For example, [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/)

Comment: Or [How does falling through cases in c work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904011/).

Comment: Or [Newbie: After adding cases to a switch in C, it breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458794/)

Comment: I find it interesting that the code above compiles.  I've never seen a situation where all of the case keywords were not in the same block.

Comment: @ThePhoton I get the point, although you can take the question to be about the funky use of the ```{}``` which isn't part of any of those linked topics

Comment: @TomCarpenter, The links are for OP more than for you.

Comment: I saw the use of such a case in [Duffs Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). I wanted to understand how the switch behaves at the assembly level. Hence i asked the question here and not on SO cause its actually an embedded issue when you talk about how assembly code behaves

Comment: If it is about assembly level stuff, why does nothing in your question reference assembly?

Comment: What i meant was not the actual assembly instructions but how does the C code behave at the assembly level. Does the switch behave as JMP instruction without checking for any conditions

Comment: @ThePhoton- Should such questions not be asked on this forum?

Comment: It would be highly educational if you made this an actual assembly question: take your code above, compile it, inspect the assembly, and see what it's doing. That will make its "true" behaviour very clear.

Comment: The alignment of the disassembly code may not be proper. The instructions are what that matter

Comment: "Does the switch behave directly as a goto label irrespective of where the case label has been placed?" Exactly! (as long as the labels are all in the statement that follows the switch, including nested sub-statements.).

Comment: @TomCarpenter  The O.P. is blocked from asking on StackOverflow, apparently.  If he keeps posting off-topic questions here, he will get blocked here too.

Comment: @NickAlexeev- Do tags have no meaning? Iv tagged this question as only a "C" related doubt. Didnt i ask a "C" question? I fail to see how it was off topic

Comment: To be fair, the [on-topic help](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site is crappy. It says that "the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications" is on-topic, but "Programming software for a PC" is off-topic. Pure, generic programming questions are neither. According to [this meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/are-pure-c-questions-on-topic), it is up to the OP to decide where to post.

Comment: People on SO mark questions like CAN mailbox implemention in C as not belonging to SO. People here say to ask assembly level C understanding questions on SO. What i dont get is, why such tags like CAN,SPI,I2C etc exist on SO and tags like C exist here. Anyways. Thanks to all who took the time to patiently answer my doubt instead of even trying to give an answer before redirecting to SO. :)

Comment: @Akshay  You asked: "Why is this question is off topic?"  Answer: "Because it's not about electronics design.  This is a pure software question.  (For some reason, you are blocked from asking on SO.  Otherwise, it would be a non-issue, and we wouldn't be discussing this.)"

Comment: @NickAlexeev- Your saying if i had this on SO this wouldnt have been an issue? What sort of "C" questions must be asked on this forum? why does SO have tags like CAN,SPI,I2C etc?

Comment: @Akshay  Tags on StackExchange are not a reliable indication of on-topicness.  Tags are relatively easy to create: it takes 300 reputation (which isn't that much).  If a stack A has a tag "X", that doesn't mean that the entire subject X will be on-topic there.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - Got the point. My bad then. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really such a thing as a nested `case` within a `case` in c, and it is not an nested switch statement (there is no `switch()`!). What you are looking at is really badly formatted code and poor use of blocks.

Essentially the code is this:

```
int main()
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
        case 4:
            b=7;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

The case of 1 falls through into the case of 4 - so basically both 1 and 4 will set `b` equal to 7.

---

In C, you can use the `{}` to define a scope. So `if` statements, functions, and so forth. You can also use them in the middle of code to define variables scoped only to that region, e.g.

```
int main() {

    ...
    {
        int a;
        //do something with a
    }
    //a goes out of scope here.
    ...
}
```

In fact you can do the same with case statements if for example you need a local variable:

```
int main()
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
        case 4: {
            int c = 1;
            //Do something with c
            b=b+c;
            break;
        } //c goes out of scope here
    }
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Adding the scope around the whole case as it stands is like in the above example. But the way it is added to the sample in the question is simply obscure - will have the same effect as in my example above, but I've only ever seen the opening `{` it after the `case  ... :`, not before.

Comment: [A SO reference for declaring variables inside a switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231198/declaring-variables-inside-a-switch-statement)